# Regular expression match 0 or exact number of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match an input string in JavaScript with 0 or 2 consecutive dashes, not 1, i.e. not range.

If the string is:

- `-g:"apple" AND --projectName:"grape"`: it should match `--projectName:"grape"`.
- `-g:"apple" AND projectName:"grape"`: it should match `projectName:"grape"`.
- `-g:"apple" AND -projectName:"grape"`: it should not match, i.e. return null.
- `--projectName:"grape"`: it should match `--projectName:"grape"`.
- `projectName:"grape"`: it should match `projectName:"grape"`.
- `-projectName:"grape"`: it should not match, i.e. return null.

To simplify this question considering this example, the RE should match the preceding 0 or 2 dashes and whatever comes next. I will figure out the rest. The question still comes down to matching 0 or 2 dashes.

1. Using `-{0,2}` matches 0, 1, 2 dashes.
2. Using `-{2,}` matches 2 or more dashes.
3. Using `-{2}` matches only 2 dashes.

How to match 0 or 2 occurrences?

Comment: If you only want to grab words preceded by zero or two dashes, why isn't `AND` selected? Please be more precise about your rules.

Comment: Let's simplify this, it should match the preceding 0 or 2 dashes and whatever comes next. I will figure out the rest. The question still comes down to matching 0 or 2 dashes.

Comment: Can you edit your question to make your requirements clearer then? Also, what language/regex flavor are you using?

Comment: Damn, I should learn writing good questions. I don't ask much questions, so am not very experienced in writing good ones. But I'm learning. ^_^. Have modified the question and added the tag.

Comment: Easy to judge, not so easy to do indeed! If you only want what's after zero/two dashes you should update your input examples as well, as they don't match your rule (`AND` would also be returned)

Comment: Saw that, but now it's confusing... Either update your rule to deal with the `AND`, or remove the input containing `AND`. Your requirements and examples are incompatible as it is.

Comment: Sorry about that, but these are *part* of real case scenarios, so the answer should comply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer**

If you split your "word-like" patterns on spaces, you can use this regex and your wanted value will be in the first capturing group:

```
(?:^|\s)((?:--)?[^\s-]+)
```

- `\s` is any whitespace character (tab, whitespace, newline...)
- `[^\s-]` is anything except a whitespace-like character or a `-`

Once again the problem is *anchoring the regex* so that the relevant part isn't completely optionnal: here the anchor `^` or a mandatory whitespace `\s` plays this role.

---

**What we want to do**

Basically you want to check if your expression (two dashes) is there or not, so you can use the `?` operator:

```
(?:--)?
```

"Either two or none", `(?:...)` is a non capturing group.

**Avoiding confusion**

You want to match "zero or two dashes", so if this is your entire regex it will *always* find a match: in an empty string, in `--`, in `-`, in `foobar`... What will be match in these string will be an empty string, but the regex will return a match.

This is a common source of misunderstanding, so bear in mind the rule that *if everything in your regex is optional, it will always find a match.*

If you want to only return a match if your entire string is made of zero or two dashes, you need to anchor the regex:

```
^(?:--)?$
```

`^$` match respectively the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Tried this, but it matches 1 dash as well.

Comment: @Eye: Still correct, I edited my answer to explain why.

Comment: I've added an example to the question. Please refer to it.

Comment: @Eye: Next time please try to provide all the information on what you want to do from the beginning, this is now a very different question...

Comment: I understand, but my example is just an example, but I want the answer to be more generic to fit any case with 0 or exact number of occurrences. So your answer should not change too much to answer the question.

Comment: Your updated answer is almost what I want except that it also matches a space when no dashes exist.

Comment: @Eye: Yep, that's why I said at the beginning that the wanted result will be in the first capturing group - it's not the whole match. Javascript doesn't support lookbehind (which is why I asked for your language), so you have to use backreferences: see [here for example](http://regex101.com/r/uY5dH7), on the low right it displays captured groups for each match.

Comment: Was about to accept this answer but found it doesn't work in the following case: `projectName:"grape"`. It should have matched as it precedes with 0 dashes. Updated the examples.

Comment: Mixed my anchors, you should use ^ instead of $

Comment: Nice! This is the closest answer though with a small inconvenience because of preceding space, but as you said, if JS doesn't support look behind, I should manually handle this unnecessary space. Since it's quite easy, I'm accepting this answer. Thank you very much for your time and continuos eagerness to help despite my faults with the question description.

Comment: @Eye: Glad I could help, but what's wrong with retrieving the data (without the space) directly from the capturing group?

Comment: Sure, if I add that logic to grab the data from the capturing group, then it solves the entire problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
a(-{2})?(?!-)
```

This is using "a" as an example. This will match a followed by an optional 2 dashes.

**Edit:**

According to your example, this should work

```
(?<!-)(-{2})?projectName:"[a-zA-Z]*"
```

**Edit 2:**
I think Javascript has problems with lookbehinds.

Try this:

```
[^-](-{2})?projectName:"[a-zA-Z]*"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Pgmb7i89Uj3m8ZMc)

Comment: Question of style I guess, but do you find `-{2}` clearer than `--`?

Comment: Haha, I see what you mean. -- would probably be simpler to put "--" in this case, but when I think two of something its just a habbit to user multipliers.

Comment: This answer should technically work, but in JavaScript (sorry, I know I didn't mention this), this RE generates an error `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: unrecognized character after (?`. @Martyn, I think your answer will have the same problem.

Comment: Because `[^-]` matches a single character, the matched value includes the space but it should not.

Comment: Here it the [JS RE Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). It supports both lookaheads and negated lookaheads through `(?=)` and `(?!)` respectively.

Comment: The problem is we need to look behind, not ahead, and this is not supported. Im not sure if there is a way of doing this 100% through Regular Expressions.